# Result: Failure Exception: TypeError: argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'dict'

Tags: python, azure

I'm having a problem with this homework where I'm sending a post request with an encoded image base64 as a json object in postman. I'm supposed to decode the json body and save it as an image on azure blob storage. I was successfully creating the blobs as txt but I haven't got much luck this time. Any help will be much appreciated

Result: Failure
Exception: TypeError: argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'dict'

[image]

Comment: Instead of pasting a screenshot of your code, please edit your question and include the actual code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Do *not* post images of code. Post your code as *formatted text*. [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for some information on formatting code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to upload image file to Azure blob storage with Azure function, you can try to use the `form` to send your image to Azure function. For example

1. add Storage connection string in `local.settings.json`

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "ConnectionString" : "",
    "ContainerName": ""
  }
}
```

2. Code

```
import logging
import os
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    try:
        file=  req.files.get('the key value in your form')
        logging.info(file.filename)
        
        connect_str=os.environ["ConnectionString"]
        container=os.environ["ContainerName"]
        
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
        blob_client =blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container,blob=file.filename)
        blob_client.upload_blob(file)
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.info(ex.args)
       
    return func.HttpResponse("ok")
```

3. Test in Postman
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

---

## Update

According to my test, if we use `base64.b64decode()` to decode, we will get bytes object. So we need to use `create_blob_from_bytes` to upload. For example

My code

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    # get image base64 string
    file=req.get_json()
    image=file['image'].replace(' ', '+')
    #decode base64 string
    data=base64.b64decode(image)
    logging.info(type(data))
    #upload
    block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='blobstorage0516', account_key='')
    container_name='test'
    blob_name='test.jpeg'
    block_blob_service.create_blob_from_bytes(container_name, blob_name, data)

  
    return func.HttpResponse(f"OK!")
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying back but I need to send the image as encoded base64 throw postman.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I send the POST request and needs to be handle in my function app. I'm successfully able to create the blobs but I only get a broken image in the url from the blobs.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0aNa.jpg)