# python azure function app define variables for path

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-functions

I have defined a out binding to store file in blobstorage:

function.json:

```
{
  "type": "blob",
  "direction": "out",
  "name": "outputBlob",
  "path": "outcontainer/{outname}",
  "connection": "storagevoyager_STORAGE"
}
```

Now i try to specify the "outname" in python code:

```
outputBlob.outname = "test.txt"
outname = "test.txt"
outputBlob.set(fileobj)
```

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function:
>   Functions..Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: No value for named parameter
>   'outname'.

So how can i define the outname in my code ? I can't find any good reference.

Do i need to update enviroment variables? Also with {rand-guid} it will work.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't be imperative about the output file name. You do have `{blobname}` and `{blobextension}` if it helps (you'll need a blob trigger to use those as output). There's also {queueTrigger} if you want to use that as your output blob name.  Docs aren't very helpful i agree. See my watermark function for an example:  https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/blob/master/v2functions/blob-trigger-watermark-blob-out-binding/function.json

Comment: thanks for you answer... so in other language like c# you can define a filename but not in `python` ? if you are sure please post as answer that i can mark as answered <3

Comment: can i get the name of the random guid ? mmm

Comment: makes no sence to me somehow i should be able to change the filename based on python code

Comment: If you're asking _Can i get the name of this thing (`"path": "my-output-container/{rand-guid}.txt"` in my code?_ then i'm afraid it's a no. That binding acts before and after your code has executed.

Comment: mm think i have to connect manually to blob storage to write a file with a normal name ?

Comment: Yes. Or write a C# function and use [imperative bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#binding-at-runtime).

Comment: mmm, unlucky that this will not work in python, i hope this will be updated one day, anyway i've changed to BlockBlobService- thanks @evilSnobu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems its impossible to change the variable with Python, in C# its possible to change.

To use it in python i am using python sdk and connect manually to my storage:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

blob_service_client = BlockBlobService(account_name="storageacc", account_key="acckey")
blob_service_client.create_container(container_name)
blob_service_client.create_blob_from_bytes(container_name="container_name", blob_name="filename.txt", blob=b"blob")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a trigger like HttpTrigger, you can actually set the {outname} if you pass outname as a param in your http request! if you are using any other triggers like service bus if you pass in the json message. You could just set the input and output binding path with the json value from the trigger json data.
take a look at this [JSON payloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#json-payloads)
i tried this and it works in python

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the output blob name with the code, it is impossible. If you want to dynamically create output blob name, you can use the binding expression `{rand-guid}` in function.json to implement it.

For example

```
{
  "type": "blob",
  "direction": "out",
  "name": "outputBlob",
  "path": "outcontainer/{rand-guid}.txt",
  "connection": "storagevoyager_STORAGE"
}
```

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns)

Comment: That i already discussed in the comments ... but for example i like to store .png and .pdf ... i cant change the extension, so in python i seems not possible to access this {variable} inside code

Comment: @Fabian According to your need, I suggest you upload file to Azure blob with python sdk by yourself instead of using Azure function output binding. Regarding how to upload, you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60807874/result-failure-exception-typeerror-argument-should-be-a-bytes-like-object-or/60824482#60824482